# ts-jest not working with NextJS + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to get Jest working again with my NextJS + TS project, I'm using ts-jest, the tests used to work but seem to have stopped working for some reason (with no changes), this is my jest config,

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    dir: './',
})

/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
const customJestConfig = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
};   

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

the error I get is `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
It's erroring on the axios import inside my tests so it maybe trying to transform axios, but I tried adding 'transformIgnorePatterns' and it didn't work either.

Comment: Need more info, Maybe provide a minimal reproduction.